# I need to know Object oriented Design

Tags: php

I need to learn about OOD(Object oriented Design ) concepts and how to use it to programming. I'm beginner for OOD. I want beginner level best tutorial. How can I get it.. when I'm searching on google there are lot of references. But I can't understand how to get the clean idea about OOD. Please give me a best reference for this....

Comment: "*object oriented php tutorial*" on google has more than half a million results - surely that's somewhere you could start.

Comment: I would recommend you to start to learn how to learn and doing research before trying to master OOP. If you didn't manage to find the official php documentation for OOP or *any* other resource, then you have a far more serious problem that should be addressed first. Programming is in fact *a lot* about research and reading documentation and continuous learning.

Comment: Thanks all of you to advice me.I'm following OOP. But I haven't a clear idea about Object Oriented Designing. That's why i asked about this question. I'm really sorry for waste your time to read this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many tutorials about OOP. Have a look at the following links.

Free:

[Codecourse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc)

[killerPHP](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/)

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Paid:

[Teamtreehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/)

[Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com)

Books:

There is a really good book called PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice, 3rd Edition by Matt Zandstra.

Best advise I can give is to not worry so much about what tutorial to start but just start. You will only learn by keep doing it (trial & error) and keep reading about it.

--Edit--

What I would advise you different from @Ema.jar is to stick to one language.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your advise. I'm beginner for this.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. keep checking out this page. I will be adding some more sources.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should start following some tutorials based on a particular language. OOP is a concept and is not related to a specific programming language but, starting with, Java, for example, you could get your hands dirty with pratical examples.

A good book to read is: [Head First Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/).
Another good idea could be to follow a university class like [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs108/)

Once you understand these concept you'll be able to apply this way of thinking to other OOP languages like, Python, Ruby or PHP.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your Option. I'm following PHP. I haven't clear idea about Object Oriented designing.